# Cakephp Security

Tags: security, cakephp, xss, csrf, xsl-fo

I am new to Security of Web apps. I am developing an application in Cakephp and one of my friends told me about the Cross-site request forgery (CSRF) and cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks etc. not sure how many more are there.

I need some help in understanding how to make Cakephp defend my web app against these. we are low budget and we cant hire a security consulant as of now. We are still developing the app and plan to release in by the end of the month. so wanna take care of the initial stuff that can help me stand un hacked ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is not (and cannot be) one tool you can deploy and then never have to think about security again. Deploying ‘anti-XSS’ hacks like CakePHP's `Sanitize::clean` will get in users' way by blocking valid input, whilst still not necessarily making the app secure. Input filtering hacks are at best an obfuscation measure, not a fix for security holes.

To have a secure web application, you must write a secure web application, from the ground up. That means, primarily, attention to detail when you are putting strings from one context into another. In particular:

- any time you write a string to HTML text content or attribute value, HTML-escape it (`htmlspecialchars()`) to avoid HTML-injection leading to XSS. This isn't just a matter of user input that might contain attacks, it's the correct way to put plain text into HTML.

  Where you are using HTML helper methods, they should take care of HTML-escaping of those elements by default (unless you turn off `escape`); it is very unfortunate that the CakePHP tutorial includes the bad practice of echoing unescaped strings into HTML for text outside of HTML helpers.
- any time you create SQL queries with string values, SQL-escape it (with an appropriate function for your database such as `mysql_real_escape_string`).

  If you are using CakePHP's ORM and not writing your own SQL you don't have to worry about this.
- avoid using user input (eg file upload names) to name files on the filesystem (generate clean unique IDs instead) or as any part of a `system()` command.
- include the [Security](http://book.cakephp.org/view/175/Security-Component) component to add a form submission token scheme that will prevent XSRF on forms generated by CakePHP.

Comment: thanks for a crash course on security. one question while using HTML Helpers doesnt - htmlspecialchars() and mysql_real_escape_string() happen automatcially ?

Comment: When using HTML helpers, `htmlspecialchars()` is done by default, yes, unless you set `'escape'=>false`. `mysql_real_escape_string()` isn't, as it doesn't make any sense to be SQL-escaping HTML-output. That needs to happen when talking to the database (and will be done automatically if you are using the ORM). `htmlspecialchars()` is needed when you are outputting content without a helper, such as inline non-form content. eg. `<p>Hello, <?php echo htmlspecialchars($name); ?>!</p>`.

Comment: "it is very unfortunate that the CakePHP tutorial includes the bad practice of echoing unescaped strings into HTML for text outside of HTML helpers"  I agree - this way many are not aware that this is really bad.

Comment: is there a way to perform it before storing to the database? as now I use h() to wrap echo calls.

Comment: @Sela: the database layer is the wrong place to be doing HTML-escaping. You cannot assume that all data will take the route form-input=>database=>HTML-output; it's entirely possible to take input from the form or other sources and echo it direct to the page (in which case you missed escaping), or to use data for non-HTML purposes (in which case you have unnecessary escapes), or to take content from the database, alter it, and write it back to the database (in which case you have double-escaping and the dreaded `&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;` explosion). Wrapping at HTML output time is correct.

Comment: (In any case you don't want HTML-escaped content in your database. It won't search, collate or slice properly.)

Answer (score 4):

Cake can be secured relatively easy (compared to self written php scripts):
http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/10/05/cakephp-security/